# XSD to define free format, except for one namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd, schema, xml-namespaces

In an XML file, I'd like to use a free format in the default namespace, but at various places some elements should be allowed that are in a specific namespace. I only want those elements to be validated. So what I want is something like this:

```
<document xmlns:x="http://myNamespace">
  <someElement1>
    <x:toBeValidated1/>
    <someElement2>
      <x:toBeValidated2 someAtt="someValue">
        <someMoreStuff/>
      </x:toBeValidated2>
    </someElement2>
  </someElement1>
</document>
```

The question is, can I write a schema to validate this? It should allow any element anywhere, but elements in the http://myNamespace namespace mu conform to their corresponding definitions in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This can *mostly* be accomplished. You'll need to define a schema that covers the types that you'll want to validate:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://myNamespace">
    <xs:element name="toBeValidated1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="toBeValidated2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="someAtt" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And import that into a schema that defines the root element of your document:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://myNamespace" schemaLocation="other.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="document" type="xs:anyType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I don't think you can get around at least defining the root element, however it can be defined in such a way that any child elements or attributes are allowed.